# If x is an element of X, and X is an element of A, what is the relation between x and A?

Tags: logic

Is there a name for that relation? Are there any interesting results from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x is an element of the union of A.

$x \in \bigcup A$.

Comment: a union of a single set? Is there a link to learn more about it?

Comment: You may say that $x$ is (one of the points) covered by $A$, but do not do that without making sure you set up such terminology. Most people use `corered by' in a different way.

Comment: @csp. $\bigcup A$ denotes (in the Set theory) the union of the set $A$.  The set of all $x$ that are element of some element of $A$. May be you would like to see that written as $\bigcup _{X\in A} X$.

Comment: @csp $\bigcup A$: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_unions]  but beware, wiki is not very precise. For example, the first sentence of [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)] does not ring correct.

Comment: Is there a general name for it? I'm not having any luck searching for union on a set.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link. That helps